# In node.js and express, how should a client send a large, up to 3k, amount of data to the server?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

the client will be sending my server a change log, containing a list of commands and parameters, JSON or not is TBD.

This payload can be a 3 or 4K not likely to be more.

What is the standard approach to deal with requirement? 
Client should send a json, containing all of the changes, as part of the request body?

Any recommendations? Lessons learned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just POST the data.  3-4 KB is nothing unless you're dealing with feature-phone WAP browsers in the middle of rural India, performance issues of the "OMG, I'm Google and care about every byte ever because of my zillion-user userbase" type, or something like that.

If you're really worried about payload size, you can gzip-base64 encode it before sending - but only do this if a) you *really* care about this (which is unlikely) and b) your payload is large enough that this saves you bandwidth.  (gzip-base64'ing small payloads often *increases* their size, since there isn't enough data to get enough compression benefit to offset the 33% size increase from base64 encoding.)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the maximun upload size with

```
app.use(express.limit('5mb'));
```

if that's an issue?

But, there shouldn't really be any limitations on this as default, except the max buffer size (which I believe is 1GB).

It also sounds like this is something that you can just post to the server with a regular POST request, in other words you use a form with a file input and just upload the file the regular way, as 4kb isn't really a big file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal JSON post to send across 3/4K of data.

You should pay more attention to what you do with the data received on the server side, whether you buffer up all data before you start processing them (store in db or elsewhere), or process them in chunks. If you are simply dumping the data into files on server, you should create a Writable stream and pump chunks of data received into the stream.

How are you going to process the received data on the server? But then, 3/4K is not really worrying amount of data.

Comment: probably have to stream it to a file and process it at the end